# Excel VBA getting error 400 on Workbooks.Open

Tags: vba, excel, google-docs

Whenever my Excel Macro hit the code below:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenThisFile, CorruptLoad:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)
```

It returns a `error 400`. The weird thing is this wasn't happening before, I do this daily. I download an excel spreadsheet/workbook from GoogleDrive (*It was initially uploaded to Google Drive and wasn't created in GoogleDrive*) then use my ExcelMacro to open the downloaded Excel file and read it's contents. The ExcelMacro then do some sorting and editing to the ExcelFile then re-upload it back to GoogleDrive to be sorted again tomorrow. I'm not sure what's going on or if the problem is with my computer or with Google making changes to their settings.

One thing I do notice, is that if I open the downloaded file first, it gives me this error before opening:

[image: EventA]

Then after trying to `Repair` the file it then gives me this result:

[image: EventB]

If I save and ignore these problems, I can do the ExcelMacro and it doesn't give me errors. So now I would have to add another step in my daily routine which is after downloading the ExcelFile from GoogleDrive, I would need to open the downloaded file, ignore all problems found and save it so when I use my ExcelMacro it doesn't give any errors.

UPDATE: Anyone got any ideas about this yet? Looks like hard to investigate but the only problem I see here is those XML part errors. I think if I can somehow stop those error messages or repair alerts then the macro would be able to open it just fine. Adding `corruptload:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile` doesn't seem to work anymore.

The whole sub/section wherein the error is triggered:

```
Sub LoadOldFiles(OpenTheFileAddress)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenTheFileAddress, corruptload:=xlRepairFile)   <---- ERROR
    If wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
    End If
    If wb.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        wb.Sheets(2).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Range("A1")
    End If
    wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

'Remove Wraptext which causes missing part of cell contents
Sheet2.Cells.WrapText = False
Sheet3.Cells.WrapText = False

'Cleanup
FormatOutputSheets
Sheet2.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Sheet3.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Application.Goto Sheet3.Range("A1"), True
Application.Goto Sheet2.Range("A1"), True
Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("A1"), True
Sheet1.Label1.Caption = Dir(OpenTheFileAddress, vbDirectory)

'Change old inactive data color to orange so we can detect the ones being transfered back to active
Sheet3.UsedRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: can you copy the file, delete all sensitive contents, and share it on Google or Dropbox? Curious to see if someone else can replicate the problem.

Comment: I'll try, I'll see if editing it online doesn't affect the reproducing of the issue

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce if I try to remove sensitive information. Basically the problem seem to be the cells with links in it. I am using Excel 2007 in my computer, could it be that when the GoogleSheet is downloaded to my PC, it downloaded a spreadsheet that is not perfectly compatible with my Excel2007? Is there any codes in VBA I can use to ignore the warnings or found unreadable contents and just do what it has to do without causing errors?

Comment: this is a shot in the dark but maybe `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before your call to `Open` method, and then `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after (to resume normal settings).

Comment: It is already there actually. I should have placed that section of my code, sorry. I updated my post above